# Maidenhead Grid Square Functions in SAS, PHP or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, sas, latitude-longitude

Conceptually I understand what I need to do. But mathmatically I'm stumped. 
I would like to create two functions preferably in SAS but PHP or JavaScript would work too. The first to convert a latitude/longitude into the Maidenhead Grid Square, the second finds the latitude and longitude for the center of the Maidenhead Grid Square given the grid square name (i.e. EM29qe78pq). I would like both to work with all 10 characters but still be flexable enough to only need 6 and 8 of them.
I've read and re-read the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maidenhead_Locator_System but always come up with the wrong values. I've Googled quite literally more than 100 times looking for help, none I found does. I've come to the realization I just am not understanding the math part of this problem. And its simple math..I'm told.
This is the SAS macro I have converting grid square to lat/lon, but while close, its not correct. Would someone care to investigate this for me and perhaps give me the answer.

%macro grid2latlong(grid);

```
field = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX';

array sparts $ 1 var1-var10;
do i = 1 to length(&grid);
    sparts{i} = substr(&grid,i,1);
    lon1 = (find(field,var1)-1) * 20 - 180;
    lat1 = (find(field,var2)-1) * 10 - 90;

    lon2 = var3 * 2;
    lat2 = var4 * 1;

    lon3 = (find(field,var5)-1) * 5/60;
    lat3 = (find(field,var6)-1) * 2.5/60;

    lon4 = var7 * 0.0083333; 
    lat4 = var8 * 0.0041666; 

    lon5 = var9;
    lat5 = var10;

    lonx = sum(lon1,lon2,lon3,lon4); 
    latx = sum(lat1,lat2,lat3,lat4); 
end;

drop i var1-var8 lon4 lat4 lon1-lon3 lat1-lat3;
```

%mend;

Comment: This would be a better question with some sample data, sample correct results, and some information for how you're getting it wrong (ie, sample wrong results).

Comment: For the macro call the parameter for testing should be EM29qe78pq. The result should be 39.202953, -94.602885 or something less than a second from that. I can usually get to 39.2000, -94.6000 in my calculation but not closer. Then center of a 10 character grid square would be about the middle of an average house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calculating the centroid, you're calculating the lower left boundary of the square, as I understand it.  To calculate the centroid, it looks like the standard Perl routine Wikipedia references appends "..55LL55LL" as needed (the first two obviously have to be present, but after that 55 or LL will be roughly the central point of the grid tile).  I assume 55LL is the "standard" given its presence there; you could calculate it more precisely by taking the average of the left boundary and the right boundary (the next left boundary).

Here's a slightly simplified version of your code above that does this.  I write it as a data step to simplify testing but of course making it a macro is trivial.  If you have FCMP (9.2+, better 9.4+) you can write it as an actual function in that of course.

```
data have;
length grid $10;
input grid $;
datalines;
AB12CD34
AB12CD
AB12CD34EF
;;;;
run;

%let grid=grid;


data want;
set have;
*Initialize some variables;
latmult=10;  *the amount to multiply latitude values by (starting out);
lonmult=20;  *the amount to multiply longitude values by (starting out);
lon=-180;  *the zero point for longitude in this system;
lat=-90;   *the zero point for latitude in this system;

*append 5's and L's to the string if it is incomplete;
*If you leave this out, this still works, but returns the edge not the center;

initial_String='LL55LL55LL';
substr(initial_String,1,length(&grid.)) = trim(&grid.);

do i = 1 to length(initial_String) by 2;

    if mod((i+1)/2,2)=1 then do;  *letters;
        if I>1 then do;  *i=1 it is initialized properly already;
            lonmult=lonmult/24;
            latmult=latmult/24;
        end;
        *rank converts "A" to 65 and up through "Z" is 90.;
        lon=sum(lon,lonmult*(rank(upcase(char(initial_String,i)))-65));
        lat=sum(lat,latmult*(rank(upcase(char(initial_String,i+1)))-65));
    end;
    else do;
        latmult=latmult/10;
        lonmult=lonmult/10;
        lon=sum(lon,lonmult*input(char(initial_String,i),1.));
        lat=sum(lat,latmult*input(char(initial_String,i+1),1.));
    end;
end;


run;
```

Comment: The example I always use is EM29qe78pq only because I know the exact answer is very  close to 39.202953, -94.602885. Your algorithm above gives 39.202777778, -94.603125  much closer than I've been able to come up with. And close enough for who its for. Thank you so much for helping with this.